# MessageReceiver class missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I could not find the class ProjectSubscriptionName/MessageReceiver and eclipse reporting ProjectSubscriptionName/MessageReceiver class can not resolved error tough the related google-cloud-pubsub jar imported to build path by defining in pom.xml file.

```
pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.0</version>
</dependency>

Need help here to find the correct jar for missing classes. Appreciate your help. Jar should be stable one not alpha/beta version.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Hi Kamal,
    Google released pubsub 1.31.0 version yesterday and pom entry below:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.0</version>
    </dependency>

    Link: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-pubsub/1.31.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ProjectSubscriptionName` and `MessageReceiver` are only defined in later versions of the client library that were in beta until version 1.31.0 was released. The newer client libraries are designed to make it easier to handle high throughput and low latency. The `MessageReceiver` interface first appeared in version 0.9.0-alpha. The `ProjectSubscriptionName` class first appeared in 0.36.0-beta.